# Combining 2 SQL queries into one table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 SQL queries. I have looked at some of the examples on the site and still confused about how to combine them. I would like both queries in one table.

Thank you for your help

Jeremy

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    "exStudent"."Student_StudentID" AS StudentID,
    "exPerson"."Person_FirstName" + ' ' + "exPerson"."Person_LastName" AS FirstLast,
    "exPerson"."Person_LastName" AS LastName,
    "exPerson"."Person_FirstName" AS FirstName,
    "exPerson"."Person_Gender" AS Gender,
    ISNULL("exStudentEnrollment"."StudentEnrollment_Building",'') AS Building,
    "exStudentEnrollment"."StudentEnrollment_Grade" AS Grade,
    ISNULL("exStudentEnrollment"."StudentEnrollment_Homeroom",'') AS Homeroom,
    ISNULL("exStudentEnrollment"."StudentEnrollment_HomeroomTeacher",'') AS HRTeacher
FROM   
    "exStudent" "exStudent"
INNER JOIN 
    "exPerson" "exPerson" ON "exStudent"."ForeignKey" = "exPerson"."ForeignKey"
INNER JOIN 
    "exPersonMailing" "exPersonMailing" ON "exPerson"."ForeignKey" = "exPersonMailing"."ForeignKey"
INNER JOIN
    "exStudentEnrollment" "exStudentEnrollment" ON "exStudent"."ForeignKey" = "exStudentEnrollment"."ForeignKey"
 WHERE
     "exStudentEnrollment"."StudentEnrollment_Current" = 1
     AND "exStudentEnrollment"."StudentEnrollment_Homeroom" <> ''
     AND "exStudentEnrollment"."StudentEnrollment_SchoolYear"= (DATENAME(YEAR, '07-01-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH, -6, GETDATE())))) + '-' + DATENAME(YEAR, '06-30-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH, +6, GETDATE())))))
ORDER BY
    Homeroom, Gender, LastName, FirstName
```

This is the second query:

```
select * 
from UserDefinedScreen --ID for "Lunch IDs" is 2

select * 
from UserDefinedField 
where UserDefinedScreen_ID = 2 --ID for "Lunch ID" field is 3

select s.StudentID, pudf.Value 
from PersonUserDefinedField pudf
join PersonUserDefinedScreen puds on pudf.PersonUserDefinedScreen_ID = puds.ID
join Person p on puds.Person_ID = p.ID
join Student s on s.Person_ID = p.ID
where pudf.UserDefinedField_ID = 3
```

Comment: You have 4 `SELECT` statements listed (and no semicolons `;` in between some of them) -- what exactly are you trying to do?  Join them side-by side, or concatenate them so you have all the rows in one big table?

Comment: Why are you aliasing your objects with the name of the object? `"exStudent" "exStudent"` is completely redundant. The points of aliasing is to provide a more succinct, meaningful, and **consistent** name for your objects.

Comment: Join them by `StudentId`

Comment: And why are you "wrapping" "everything" "in" "double" "quotes" "?". It really makes this difficult to read and provides zero benefit. Also, don't use varchar without length. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length

Comment: @SeanLange, I can't speak to the query the OP put up, but I see the double-quote abuse from queries that were designed in SAS BusinessObjects, where BO builds out the query from the GUI and then someone pulls the query from the editor and drops it into SSMS. I reflexively use SQL Prompt to clean them up when I encounter them, but not everyone I work with is so inclined.

Comment: @EricBrandt yikes. I shudder that a tool actually uses such an abysmal practice like that.

Comment: Sorry, I just copied it from SAS.  I usually go back through and remove the quotes and redundant code. I am trying to combine the two select statements.  When I run this in MS Server I get two tables.